# bypass silverlight tcp port restrictions

Tags: c#, silverlight, sockets, silverlight-4.0, tcp

Is there a way to bypass the Silverlight port range (4502-4532) security restriction for TCP connections?
Maybe a 3rd party implementation of TcpSocket that does not enforce the 4502-4532 port range?

Comment: I doubt it.  The security restrictions in the plugin would make a 3rd party implementation impossible I believe.

Comment: I tried to look at the code via reflector. specifically at CrossDomainSocketPolicyManager. It seems that the restriction is just embedded in the code - so I think a 3rd party implementation might be able to work

Comment: you could create tcp proxy to channel trafic from 4502-4532 ports to some different range, but other than that...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way around this restriction unless you are willing to turn your application into a out of browser app with elevated trust.

A "3rd party" implementation would still need at some point to interoperate with unmanaged network layers, the Silverlight plugin provides no way for that to happen except through its own runtime.

The restriction is there for a reason and even if you could find a way round it you could never be sure that such a hole would never be closed.